# Display elements in a dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a page where I have an empty dropdown list, I need to use radio buttons in order to generate the elements inside. everything is working perfectly, I am getting the data when I debug the code, the one problem I have which is a really simple problem is that I can't append the data into the dropdown list for some reason, I have tried almost all the answers I found on here, but non of them worked.

this is my procedure class, i call this from my controller

```
public class Procedures
    {

        public List<SelectListItem> SelectAnswer(int questionid)
        {
            List<SelectListItem> ds = new List<SelectListItem>();
            //      var connection = ConfigurationManager.
            //ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString;
            String Con = CONNECTION STRING ONLY;
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Con))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SelectAnswer", con))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@questionid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = questionid;

                        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                        var dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        while (dataReader.Read())
                        {
                            var item = new SelectListItem();
                            item.Text = dataReader["QuestionDesc_F"].ToString(); 
                            
                            ds.Add(item);
                        }
                    }
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            return ds;


        }

    }
}
```

my controller

```
 public ActionResult SelectAnswer(int questionid)
        {
            Question_OptionIndexModel provinces = new Question_OptionIndexModel();
            
            var ds = new Procedures().SelectAnswer(questionid);
            
          

            
            return Json(ds.ToList());



        }
```

view

This is where it all goes wrong, data is being sent and I can listen to it with my console; so I know the data is being transferred correctly, problem is with the append, the jquery function is kind of weird but it was my last try before I knew I needed help

ps. I know I am only sending text from my procedure class, but I was putting it to the side until the text worked, I was using static variable that increments by one as the value

```js
$("input[name='radio']").on("change", function addQuestion() {
  $('#answerSelectList').dataTable().fnClearTable();
  var questionid = this.value;
  var eleUpdate = $('#offerDropdown');
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: '@Url.Action("SelectAnswer", "Question_Option")',
    ajaxasync: true,
    data: {
      questionid: questionid
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $(eleUpdate).find('option').remove();
      $(eleUpdate).append('<option value="">@GetResource("Label.Global.Select")</option>');
      $.each(data, function(index) {
        var $option = $('<option>');
        $option
          .val(index)
          .text(data[index].text);
        $(eleUpdate).append($option);
      });
      $(eleUpdate).val('').trigger('change');
    },
    error: function(data) {}
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-control">
  <div id="radio">
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" value="1" /><label for="radio1">Choice 1</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" value="2" /><label for="radio2">Choice 2</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio" value="3" /><label for="radio3">Choice 3</label>
  </div>
</div>
<select id="offerDropdown" class="form-control">
</select> //I need to append here
```

Comment: Can you describe "weird" a bit more concise? what happens in your success handler? Is the returned data valid?

Comment: The data is valid, the only problem I have is that I can't figure out how to append the data[index].text to the dropdown list, everything else is working properly. Tried every solution on stackoverflow, many have the same problem, none worked. when in browser console the data[index].text shows the correct values, I just need a way to append the text to the dropdownlist

Comment: The problem is with the append method in the ajax, tried all different types of appends, none worked.

Comment: The is a simple mistake that I can quickly think of: You are adding var eleUpdate = $('#offerDropdown'); and calling append on $(eleUpdate) which is $($('#offerDropdown')). That is the reason why it is not working. Instead, try eleUpdate.append() .

Comment: Why you use `$(eleUpdate).append(xxxx)` to append data? Just `eleUpdate.append()`

Comment: As I mentioned, I have tried almost every single way of appending, none worked, even this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the controller

```
  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetCustomerByBranch(string example)
        {
            MyContext db = new MyContext();

            var _Customer = Common.getDataCollection(example);

            var result = _Customer.OrderBy(a => a.Code).Select(a => new SelectListItem { Value = a.Pkey.ToString(), Text = a.Code + " " + a.Name })
              .ToList();

            return Json(result);

            
        }
```

This is part of my view. When the customer change the value of the example dropdownlist, the customer dropdownlist will be referesh.

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ExampleId, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.ExampleId, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>

<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CustomerId, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CustomerList, Model.CustomerList, "-Select-", new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>


@section Scripts {

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryAjax")


 <script>

        $("#ExampleId").change(function () {

            $.ajax({
                url: "/Customer/GetCustomerByBranch",
                type: "post",
                data: {
                    example: $("#ExampleId").val()
                }
            }).done(function (response) {
                $("#CustomerId").empty();
                $.each(response, function (i, item) {
                    $("#CustomerId").append($("<option>").text(item.Text).val(item.Value));
                });
            });

        });


    </script>}
```

You may add alert in the javascript to check which section that the script can reach and remember you may have to clear cache after you modify and re-run the project.

Comment: Do u use entity framework?

Comment: yes, i also tried getting the data using entity framework instead of the procedure, they both get the data correctly, my problem is with the appending.

Comment: var ds = _unitOfWork.Question.GetAll().Where(a => a.QuestionType_ID == questionid).Select(r => new
            {
                r.QuestionID,
                r.QuestionDesc_F,



            }).ToList(); this also works and gets the data, i can't append to the dropdown list

Comment: The code I send you is a working of my project. Maybe I send you my project code?

Comment: Yes please i would very much appreciate it      .

Answer (score 0):

was inside a wrong div, just moved it to a different place.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).